# Entity framework Calling 'Read' when the datareader is closed

Tags: entity-framework

I have had a breakdown on my webhost. Now finally it is up again, and I have yet to know what the technicians fixed.
The problem is now I receive the error:

```
Calling 'Read' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Calling 'Read' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation.

Source Error: 

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

    Stack Trace:   

[InvalidOperationException: Calling 'Read' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation.]
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead() +93
   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() +30
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +119
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +5
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +25
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +43
   System.Linq.Queryable.Count(IQueryable`1 source) +240
   BusinessLayer.Car.GetCarCount() in xxx
   UserControls_SiteInfo.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +225
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

I have not changed anything, so could it be some permissions? I can still log onto my database with the same credentials so it is not the login info. Anyone have an idea?

UPDATE: I have found out that I get the error when I try to convert the IQuery to a list. I never received the error before, does this give any of you a clue what could be wrong?

Comment: what happens when you do a direct SQL query? (not using linq-to-sql)

Comment: I have found out that it is an error with either my database or with the network at my webhost, so it has nothing to do with the entity framework itself.

Comment: Changing `IEnumerable` to `IList` resolved the issue for me
I'm returning a complex object from a sproc

Comment: This error can also occur if tables that are part of a relation are left out of the model. Even if you do not intend to use a particular table it should be brought in if it has a relation with a table you are using.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The entity framework uses lazy evaluation. This means that the query is not actually executed against the database when you create it, it is executed when you actually need the data out. Consequently, the data context must still be open when you process the query.

Converting the query to an IList will force the query to be executed. If the data context is closed at this point you will get an error like this.

I can't explain why you didn't get this before if you haven't changed any code, but this is what I would be looking at.

Perhaps post your code, this might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: Pointing out the issue of Lazy Loading and forcing Entity Framework to load the content into memory solved my issue. I use `.ToList()` to force a query's results into memory before the query's hosting EF Context was disposed.

Comment: when nothing changed in code and there was a breakdown on webhost, therefore, it has nothing to do with entity framework. The error probably accrued because of allocation error or consistency error in database and database must be corrected immediately.

Answer (score 4):

I started getting this error after my computer shut down unexpectedly.  After reading this thread, the answer by James Ellis-Jones led me to using SQL profiler to get the SQL being executed when .ToList() was called, and I ran the SQL in SQL Server Management Studio.  This is the message that SQL Server returned:

SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0xb6a6f70e; actual: 0xb6a74f0e). It occurred during a read of page (1:50284) in database ID 5 at offset 0x000000188d8000 in file 'D:\Work\DATABASES\SQL2008R2\xxxxx.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

So in my case, the unexpected shutdown left the database in an inconsistent state.  I was able to successfully restore a database backup and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I had pretty much this error, and it turned out to be a consistency error in the SQL database.  I confirmed this by running a query in SQL Management Studio on the tables involved in the line concerned, and although I got data back, there was an error message too that advised of the problem.  I imagine similar things could happen with Entity Framework running against other databases.

Comment: Thanks i also have issue in database,Event Select * was not working ...Error was Msg 605, Level 21, State 3, Line 1
Attempt to fetch logical page (1:640) in database 30 failed. It belongs to allocation unit 7946994385574035456 not to 72057594046709760.