# Store a stored procedure result set in application variable error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I am a junior dev and I am new to application variables. I have a stored procedure that returns a small lookup table. I want to store the result set in an application variable so it is available to the app but not sessionable like a static would be.
**In my global.asax :**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Application["lookup"] = FunctionThatGetsSprocResult();                      
    }
```

**My db call function** :

```
  internal static ObjectResult<GetLookupTable_Result> FunctionThatGetsSprocResult()
    {
        ObjectResult<GetLookupTable_Result> result;
        using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
        {
            result = db.GetLookupTable();               
        }
        return result;          
    }
```

**In my controller :**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myVar = (ObjectResult<GetLookupTable_Result>)HttpContext.Application["lookup"];

        return View();
    }
```

Ignoring the fact that it doesn't actually do anything with myVar, when i quickwatch it, I get an error ***calling 'read' when the datareader is closed is not a valid operation*** upon googling found some threads but ultimately not helpful. I would like to store the result set in a manageable structure like a dictionary or something. 
MVC 4.5, EF 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following thread [calling 'read' when the datareader is closed is not a valid operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972025/entity-framework-calling-read-when-the-datareader-is-closed) the query gets executed when requested,if lazy evaluation is enabled(you can disable it if you like).When you open the quickwatch that forces the query to be executed.By that time apparently the datareader is closed so the query can't be performed hence the error. What you need to do is call ToList() right after you call FunctionThatGetsSprocResult().

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    Application["lookup"] = FunctionThatGetsSprocResult();
    ((ObjectResult<GetLookupTable_Result>)Application["lookup"]).ToList();              
}
```

This way you are requesting for the query results to be fetched!
Or you can change the FunctionThatGetsSprocResult and call ToList() in there:

```
internal static ObjectResult<GetLookupTable_Result> FunctionThatGetsSprocResult()
{
    ObjectResult<GetLookupTable_Result> result;
    using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
    {
        result = db.GetLookupTable();               
    }
    result.ToList();
    return result;          
}
```

Comment: Your analysis is correct, but the solution isn't. The function should return `db.GetLookupTable().ToList()`, so the query is executed before the context is disposed. This means that the return type of the method should be changed as well.

Comment: Building upon the answer from @Sotiris and the comment by Gert, I ended up with doing: db.GetLookupTable().ToDictionary(x=>x.Id, x=>x.Name); and in my controller: var myVar = (Dictionary<int, string>)HttpContext.Application["lookup"]; I am using a dictionary in this instance because it is only going to be key value pairs. Thanks to both!

Comment: Gert's proposal is cleaner but the dictionary is good also.Glad i could help!